# how to know the difference between the sum of the values of the even index and the sum of the values of the odd index in an array (recursive code)

Tags: c, recursion, function-definition

(recursive solutions only ) I'm using the function : int diff(char str[],int i)
the input is the string : 123, the sum of the values in the even indexes is 1+3=4
the sum of the values in the odd indexes is 2
so the  difference between the sum of the values of the even index and the sum of the values of the odd index in an array **is** :4-2= 2.

I have written this in the main but its not right ,how can I fix my code ??? :

```
printf("Enter a string:");
if(scanf("%s",str)!=1)
{
    printf("Input error");
    return 1;
}

printf("The difference is: %d", diff(str, 0));
return 0;
```

and outside the main was the function :

```
int diff (char str[], int i)
{
    if(str[i]=='\0' || i>=100)
        return 0;
    if(i%2==0)
        return (str[i]+diff(str,i+1));
    else
        return (-str[i] +diff(str,i+1));
}
```

Comment: Take this as an opportunity to learn how to *debug* your programs. For example using a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. For each recursive call write down the current (before recursive call) value of `i` and `str[i]` on paper and step into the call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code, as written, is not working because it is not converting the character codes held in `str` to integer values in the range 0-9.

If the input to the diff function was "12345" then inspection of the values of str[0], str[1], ... str[5] either with the debugger or printing them out would show them to be (assuming an ASCII-derived encoding):

```
49 50 51 52 53
```

Luckily, (and thanks to user @SomeProgrammerDude for pointing this out), the C standard requires (see, for example: [ISO/IEC 9899:TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) §5.2.1, paragraph 3):

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

What this means in practice is you can convert the characters '0','1',...,'9' to their equivalent values by subtracting '0'.

```c
int value = str[i] - '0';
```

Adding this to code gives a working version of `diff`:

```c
int diff (char str[], int i)
{  
    if(str[i]=='\0' || i>=100)
        return 0;
    int value = str[i] - '0';
    if(i%2 == 0)
        return (value + diff(str, i+1));
    else
        return (-value + diff(str, i+1));
}
```

Comment: The definition (or at least assignment to) `value` should be after you check for the string terminator or out of bounds index.

Comment: I ran the code u gave me right now and it correct but I don't know why it is necessary to make sure that the value are from 0 to 9 ?although I just typed values from 0 to 9 as my input .

Comment: Yup, you are correct. (Although it would not have caused an incorrect answer. Just unneeded code execution)

Comment: @dany You still need to convert from the character codes held in the string to values. The string "123" will typically hold character codes 49,50,51. To convert these to 1,2,3 you need to subtract the character code for '0' (which is pretty much always 48 on modern computers) so 49-48, 50-48, 51-48 -> 1,2,3

Comment: oh I got it now(the value of the asci table ....thanks

Comment: @dany perhaps I could have explained it a little better. I will update the answer with a bit more explanation.

Comment: @dany E.g. `'1' - '0' == 1` is a requirement by the C language specification. It must apply to all systems where C is implemented, irregardless of character encoding. However, that requirement is only for digits, no other types of characters.

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude I was not 100% sure whether the standard guaranteed that (although it holds for EBCDIC too). This is useful additional information!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your input on how to improve this answer. In addition to moving the `value` assignment, I've also now included a quote and citation from the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be:

```
int diff (const char str[])
{
    if (str[0] == '\0')
        return 0;
    if (str[1] == '\0')
        return str[0] - '0';

    return str[0] - str[1] + diff(str + 2);
}
```